# Laravel 5.1 translate an array pass to blade

Tags: laravel, localization, laravel-5.1, translate

I have this in my controller

```
public function editProfile(Request $request){
  $question1 = Question::where('group',1)->lists('question', 'id');
  $question2 = Question::where('group',2)->lists('question', 'id');

  return view('user', compact(''question1', 'question2'));
}
```

---

```
$question = {\"1\":\"What is the first name of your best friend in high school?\",\"2\":\"What was the name of your first pet?\",\"3\":\"What was the first thing you learned to cook?\",\"4\":\"What was the first film you saw in the theater?\"}

$question2 = {\"5\":\"Where did you go the first time you flew on a plane?\",\"6\":\"What is the last name of your favorite elementary school teacher?\",\"7\":\"In What city or town does your nearest sibling live?\"}
```

I would like to translate the value in both question 1 and question 2 and pass it to user blade without changing the key, Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by changing the key? the key of what?

Answer (score 0):

As specified at the [localization doc](https://laravel.com/docs/master/localization), you need to populate a `lang` file with translation strings. So, let's say you want to show both Spanish and English strings.  In this case you'd need to create two files: `/resources/lang/en/messages.php` and `/resources/lang/es/messages.php`. The content of one of those files would be somewhat like this:

```
<?php

// resources/lang/es/messages.php

return [
    'welcome' => 'Bienvenido'
];
```

This way, you could access the strings in there with the following method: `__('messages.welcome')`, which would return the string for the language set on your `config/app.php` -- the default entry is `en`, by the way, but you can set it to whatever you want. The value in there will define which language will be chosen when selecting strings.

Another method to create translation strings is using the string itself as key, storing them in a JSON file instead of PHP. For example, the following translation string:

```
{
    "I love programming.": "Me encanta programar."
}
```

would be accessible through this: `__('I love programming.')`.

Having said that, you may solve your problem through the two methods presented above. You could store in your DB keywords for the questions instead of the whole text, and create translation for as many languages as you want. Also, you could keep the questions in your database and create translation strings for those questions. Finally, you'd need to iterate over the fetched entries and translate each one of them, or use some Collection helper to do the hard work for you, like [transform](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-transform) or [map](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-map).